# test for difference of a (percentage) difference in continuous measure between groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Is there a statistical test to determine if a mean difference between two samples is significantly greater than another mean difference in another two (independent) samples?

To be clearer:
I have two groups (diseased and healthy) and two gender groups (female and male).

Say the mean of diseased female is x1_mean; mean of healthy female is x2_mean;
the mean of diseased male is y1_mean; mean of healthy male is y2_mean

I define

x_mean_diff = x1_mean – x2_mean; 
percentage difference for females = (x_mean_diff) / x2_mean

y_mean_diff = y1_mean – y2_mean
percentage difference for males = (y_mean_diff) / y2_mean

I would like to find out if the percentage difference for females is significantly different from the percentage difference for males.

Is there a way to do this? I am unable to use the usual tests because these are summary scores (I don’t have a distribution, so I can’t find a standard error for the percentage differences).

I know I can test for an interaction (sex * group) in an ANOVA to determine if the raw values are different – but I want to test the percentage differences. Also, in addition to significance, I would like to get a confidence interval of the difference of the percentage differences.

Please let me know if I'm being unclear. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! So you have a *mean* for each sex-group pairing (e.g., healthy-female) but you don’t have the scores for each individual? If you don’t, I would assume you don’t have any measure of the spread of the individual values. Right?

Comment: Sorry I have been out unwell. I do have the individual values!